# Wireless Mouse Lag

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, usb, mouse

I have a mid-2014 MBP retina that runs OSX El Capitan (10.11.6). I'm trying to use my wireless Logitech mouse (Anywhere MX, the first edition), but there is an intermittent lag problem. Sometimes it lags so much that the cursor does not move smoothly across the screen. There doesn't seem to be a particular app that's running that causes it. Here's what I know:

- I suspect the mouse isn't the problem because the issue repeats with another wireless Logitech mouse.
- When I switch to an old wired mouse, the problem disappears.
- A reboot *sometimes* works.
- I did not observe a particular trend in memory usage while this happens. In other words, the rest of the system functions ok. The trackpad works fine.

How can I diagnose the problem?

Comment: Change the batteries; Move the antenna away from anything metal or electronic & nearer to the mouse; Update the Logitech drivers; Bypass Logitech & test with 3rd party drivers [SteerMouse, USB Overdrive etc]

Comment: I agree with Tetsujin, my mouse recently had some trouble after I connected a USB device in front of the wireless receiver. Devices or other metal parts can cause interference/impediment and impair the connection between your device and the receiver. Make sure that your receiver and mouse have line-of-sight contact, that helped me.

Comment: @Tetsujin I mean I have a usb thumb drive in the other usb port, but unplugging it doesn't solve the issue. There is nothing else connected to the computer that wasn't there before these issues popped up. I'll try updating/changing drivers now.

Answer (score 2):

**Radio Frequency Interference**

There does exist a problem with radio interference when using 2.4 GHz devices (Logitech Unifying Receiver / Bluetooth) along with a USB 3.x peripheral connected to the computer. This interference is known to cause significant lag in the mouse response [(Intel, 2012)](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/io/universal-serial-bus/usb3-frequency-interference-paper.html). I would begin by investigating if this issue applies to you before moving on to other sources.

Simply identify if any USB 3.x peripherals are connected. If so, disconnect them and consider if the cursor movement changes. The USB 3.x issue causes erratic behavior in the cursor which should then be gone [(Logitech, 2014)](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023414273). Remedies can then be taken such as changing up the USB port usage, and moving the mouse receiver closer to the mouse.